# How to keep graph format in Excel when data changes?

Tags: excel, vba, graph, charts, format

I have a series of graphs in Excel that I previously formatted. The data to be graphed comes from a dynamic series where user selects an element and then graphs show the concentration of the selected element.

[image: Format wanted]

When I select another element I don't want the format to change as it currently does:

[image: Line formatting changes, width and -----]

I have already tried to lock formating for all my charts with:
         .ProtectFormatting = True

The sheet is protected and users can only select the element they want to graph. By selecting the element, the lines to be plotted update (using a dynamic pointer) but so does the format.

I've tried to save the graph as a template and then use the template for every graph but I am not sure if this is the right thing to do. The funny thing is that when I reselect the formatted graph (Cu) I get back the format I saved! Do I have to manually (or with a macro) format all 25 possibles graphs? I have 3 different graphs for every element...

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve dynamic charts. It appears that you apply a technique where there are several series in a chart and you use VBA to show/hide series based on the user's selection.

An alternative would be to have a chart with only ONE series and let the user selection change the data for the chart.

If you want more precise advice you will need to share your code/approach.

Comment: Hello Teylyn, I am not using VBA for this specific part. Only using formulas to graph a scatter plot with a line.

Comment: Current formula is: =SERIES(Scenarios!$N$2,Scenarios!$A$3:$A$7,'J2.xlsm'!ele1data,1) where ele1data1 is a dynamic range that comes from the element selection. The element selection changes the column so new data draws a new graph.

Comment: I would like to know if there is a command in VBA that I could use to make the graph looks the same no matter where the dynamic range data is being pointed. Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Then, when I export this sheets to a new document format changes again! How do I preserve the graphs as they are? I am doing all the calculations with vba and I just want to export selected sheets to a new Excel file that user can work with. Could you please advice regarding graph formating?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case where unchecking the obscure property "Properties Follow Chart Data Point" would help.

This obscure setting means that if you customize your chart, then change the data, the customization is lost because the chart no longer points to the original data, for which you made the customizations.

So format your chart. Co to File > Options > Advanced, scroll down the the Charts section, and UNCHECK Properties Follow Chart Data Point for Current Workbook.

Then change the chart's source data.

See [Properties Follow Chart Data Point](https://peltiertech.com/properties-follow-chart-data-point/) for a detailed description of this setting.

[image: Properties Follow Chart Data Point]